# Right-click "Open" with arguments

Tags: windows, registry, right-click

I would like to add an entry to the Windows right-click menu that only appears when I right click on a .exe or .msi file. If the entry is selected, the exe file will be executed (like Open) but with a fixed text string as its argument.

I guess this should be possible with a registry key - any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an `.exe` file, you can do the following in the registry:

1. Under `HKEY_Classes_Root`, find key `.exe`
2. Read the `(Default)` value (this is usually `exefile`)
3. Under `HKEY_Classes_Root`, find key `exefile` (or whatever you found in step 2)
4. Under `exefile\shell` create a new key, with a name matching what you want to see in the context menu (say, "Open With My App")
5. Under your new key, create a new key called `command`
6. Set the `(Default)` value of this key to whatever commandline you want to execute.  The name of the file you clicked on can be entered using the token `%1`.  So, for example, you could set the value to `notepad.exe %1` to edit the executable in Notepad.

A similar pattern will work for other file types.

Comment: Thanks. But that's not quite what I meant. I want to actually execute the clicked-on exe or msi file and pass a fixed string as its argument. So if the right-clicked file is blah.exe then I want blah.exe MYARG to be executed. There is an open\command entry which is "%1" %* which seems to be almost what I want so I set my new entry to "%1" MYARG but according to ProcessExplorer the exe is being executed without any arguments. Any idea what is wrong with my command entry?

Comment: As far as I know, your entry is correct.  Have you tried this with a test application to see what's being passed?

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the wrong exe in Process Explorer! "%1" MYARG works great. Thanks.

Comment: @appleton is it working for you? I am facing issue on the same if anyone help

Answer (score 2):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe\shell\Copy Address\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\CopyAddress.exe %1 "

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.msi\shell\Copy Address\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\CopyAddress.exe %1 "
```

Change path and menu name(CopyAddress) as per your choice.