# Add options to program's right-click menu

Tags: vb.net, windows, windows-shell, right-click

I have a small program that reads a CSV file and outputs it in a different format.
Sometimes I want a different output format so currently I just have another version of the program compiled with slightly different code (it has no GUI, you just click on the exe and it does its job).

Is there a way I can add an option to the context menu of this program to use the different output option, perhaps by running it with a command-line argument?

I mean when right-clicking on the exe file itself, so before it is actually running.

Anything I can find when searching for answers is about editing the shell, via the registry or some other way, however I only want the option to show for this program, not every file in Windows.

Code for the command line that I would be using:

```
If Environment.GetCommandLineArgs.Count <> 1 Then
  If Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(1) = "/output2" Then
    'do stuff
  End If
End If
```

Comment: The feature you are requesting is associated with the GUI. All the features associated with files are managed by Windows Explorer (e.g., the right-click menu of a file's icon); you can modify that but involves various Registry modifications not completely straightforward to be performed. Also the second alternative (command-line argument? Sure! Just change the inputs of your program) you are asking does not seem to be related at all with the first one. Also bear in mind that you have to show some effort/knowledge before asking (e.g., show your code). Please, correct something of this.

Comment: PS: the registry editing option is not a programming-related question and thus, in case of choosing this option (and once properly formatted and after showing your knowledge/effort), perhaps you should ask it in another site (e.g., SuperUser).

Comment: @varocarbas The relation between the two points is that I want to pass the command line depending on whether the program was run from the context menu option or not.

This is the closest answer I can find:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991209/add-options-to-programs-right-click-menu

Comment: However I do not want to affect all exe files, just this one.  I will try Super User if this is not a question for here, thank you.

Comment: "This is the closest answer I can find" by adding a link to this question?! LOL. You ("the peculiars") are back? Let's stop it here. Better wait for the next helper.

Comment: You could also do this. 1) Create the .EXE that needs the command line argument; 2) Create 2 .BAT files that call and provide different arguments to the .EXE. Now you can just run the .BAT files and all will be good too.

Comment: @varocarbas I think that was fairly obviously a mistake... but hey if you honestly think I'm just here to troll then I'll be more than happy to wait for the next helper.  This was the correct link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881938/right-click-open-with-arguments

Comment: @Styxxy Yes, I could do the same by creating a shortcut with the arguments included, but I wanted to avoid having two separate things to click on.  Partly because I thought it seemed neater this way and partly because I just wanted to learn how to do it!

Comment: Sorry, I have had a bad day.

Comment: Be pragmatic. Don't try to make things too complex. The "solution" (or rather, way to easily make it work) is almost no work and doesn't involve any complex things. What is the difference between choosing the correct .BAT and right click + choosing the context menu item? I actually prefer the first way ... it is easily used on any (Windows) computer.